# Checar se nome de usuário é único em tempo real

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Olá, galera!
Atualmente, para verificar se um nome de usuário é único, faço da forma mais básica. Envio o POST para uma página PHP que verifica no MySQL, só depois retorna o erro.
**cadastro.php:**

```
<form role="form" action="https://<?php print $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/cadastro/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Usuário</label>
    <input name="usuario" type="text" class="form-control" minlength="4" placeholder="Digite um usuário único..." required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Criar</button>
</form>
```

**verifica.php:**

```
<?php
  $SqlCheck = $ConDB -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ContUser` FROM 
  `usuarios` WHERE `userName`=:USER;");
  $SqlCheck -> bindParam(":USER", $_POST['usuario']);
  $SqlCheck -> execute();
  $RowCheck = $SqlCheck -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $ContUser = $RowCheck -> ContUser;

  if ($ContUser == 0) {
    /* Realiza o cadastro */
  } else {
    echo 'Usuário já existe';
  }
?>
```

É possível fazer essa verificação enquanto digita no input, por exemplo, a partir do 4 caractere é mostrado na linha inferior se o usuário já existe? Em tempo real?

Talvez em jQuery ou ajax dê para fazer, mas não manjo nada dessas linguagens.

Comment: O ruim disso é que depois do 4º caractere vai estressar seu servidor com sucessivos requests.

Comment: Eu acho isso interessante, mas não sou muito aprofundado nisso porque nunca precisei ou não achei necessário aos meus projetos. Mas para evitar o muitos requests ao banco, o que seria péssimo, talvez uma ideia seria criando um arquivo de texto com todos os nomes de usuários já cadastrados e, em vez de consultar o banco, consultar esse arquivo. E ir atualizando esse arquivo de tempo em tempo.

Comment: Tem quantos nomes na tabela?

Comment: Hoje há somente um. O sistema ainda não está online.
Quero aprender fazer igual no cadastro do Gmail. Quando tira o foco do input, ele diz se já existe usuário, na div logo abaixo:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/crie_sua_conta_do_google_-_mozilla_firefox_2017-11-01_21-48-14-png

Comment: A partir do quarto caractere então eu não existiria hahaha

Comment: Dá pra fazer numa boa (e sem estressar o servidor) se você fizer um timer. Por exemplo, quando o campo muda, aguarda um tempinho e faz a checagem, assim não fica disparando requisições à toa enquanto digita. É como muitos sistemas em produção fazem hoje. Muitas vezes a resposta está nos próprios sites que você já visitou com o recurso. Ou faz só na perda de foco mesmo, aí é muito menos requisição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pagina senddata.html**

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkname()
{
 var name=document.getElementById( "UserName" ).value;

 if(name.length >3)
 {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'checkdata.php',
          data: {
           user_name:name,
          },
          success: function (response) {
               $( '#name_status' ).html(response);
               if(response=="OK")   
               {
                return true;    
               }
               else
               {
                return false;   
               }
          }
      });
 }
 else
 {
  $( '#name_status' ).html("");
  return false;
 }

}

function checkall()
{
 var namehtml=document.getElementById("name_status").innerText;
 alert(namehtml);

 if(namehtml=="OK")
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="insertdata.php" onsubmit="return checkall();">
 <input type="text" name="username" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname();">
 <span id="name_status"></span>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

**Pagina checkdata.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
{
 $name=$_POST['user_name'];

 $checkdata=$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE name = '$name'");

 $row = $checkdata->fetch_row();

 if ($row[0] > 0)
 {
  echo "Nome já existe";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "OK";
 }
 exit();
}
```

**Pagina insertdata.php**

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
{

    $name = $_POST['username'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");


    $mysqli->query("Insert into user (name) values ('".$name."')");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou divinamente! Era exatamente o que estava procurando.
Obs.: em "url: 'checkdata.php'" precisei alterar para "url: 'https://meusite.com.br/verificarusuario/'", pois uso url amigável e não estava encontrando o arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia envolver em um método essa verificação, e fazer um evento no click de um butão chamando o Ajax para verificar se existe o usuário e retornar um resultado conforme o resultado vc faria algo;
Vamos supor que vc tenha um Butão e quando clicar no Butão o evento chama o Ajax para ir no seu arquivo php que tem a método realTime(). No Método vc return para o Ajax um json com o valor se verdadeiro Cadastro feito com sucesso, se não exibe ja existe o úsuario.

```
<?php
public function realTime(){
$SqlCheck = $ConDB -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ContUser` FROM 
`usuarios` WHERE `userName`=:USER;");
$SqlCheck -> bindParam(":USER", $_POST['usuario']);
$SqlCheck -> execute();
$RowCheck = $SqlCheck -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$ContUser = $RowCheck -> ContUser;

  if ($ContUser == 0) {
   return json_encode('Cadastro Realizado com sucesso!');
  } else {
    return json_encode('Usuário já existe');
  }
}
?>




<button id="verificaUser"></button>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#verificaUser').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
       url: 'caminho/da/funcaoQueVericaSeTemOUsuarioNoBanco.php',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function(e){
         alert(e);
       }
      });
   });
})
```