# Function em PHP de verificação de informação no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, funções

Olá, preciso verificar no fomulário cadastro, se o nome do usuário que foi passado já existe no banco de dados. Gostaria da ajuda de como faço uma function em PHP ou javascript que faça essa consulta, sem usar uma framework.

A única maneira que conseguir foi a seguinte:

```
<?php
require_once('../conecta.php'); 

$nomeProfessor=$_POST['tNomeProfessor'];
$usuarioProfessor=$_POST['tUsuarioProfessor'];
$matriculaProfessor=$_POST['tMatriculaProfessor'];
$emailProfessor=$_POST['tEmailProfessor'];
$senhaProfessor=$_POST['tSenhaProfessor'];
$redigitarProfessor=$_POST['tRedigitarProfessor'];
```

// Verficar se o nome de usuário já existente

```
$val=true;
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM professor WHERE usuarioProfessor='$usuarioProfessor'");
$linha = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
if($linha >= 1){
do{
$val = false;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Nome de usuário já existente!");
location.href="javascript:history.go(-1)";    
</script>';
} while ($val == true);
}
```

// Inserir no Banco de dados

```
mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO professor (nomeProfessor, usuarioProfessor, matriculaProfessor, emailProfessor, senhaProfessor, redigitarProfessor) VALUES ('$nomeProfessor', '$usuarioProfessor', '$matriculaProfessor', '$emailProfessor', '$senhaProfessor', '$redigitarProfessor')");

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

// Mensagem de cadastrado com sucesso

```
if (isset($_GET['cadastradoSucesso']) && ($val == true)) {

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Cadastrado com sucesso!");
location.href="cadastroProfessor.php";    
</script>';
}       
?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Checar se nome de usuário é único em tempo real](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251805/checar-se-nome-de-usu%c3%a1rio-%c3%a9-%c3%banico-em-tempo-real)

Comment: Não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

**Uma outra maneira para você usar:**

> Atualmente é recomendado o uso da biblioteca PDO por ser bastante seguro, facilitar a migração para outros bancos, além de oferecer uma API concisa entre eles.

```
if (isset($_POST['tUsuarioProfessor'])) {

    $usuarioProfessor=$_POST['tUsuarioProfessor'];

    //verifica se a variavel é uma variável vazia
    if (empty($usuarioProfessor)) {
        echo "Campo usuario obrigatorio!";
    } else {
        //conexão 
        //require_once('../conecta.php');
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_DB', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM professor WHERE usuarioProfessor = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $usuarioProfessor);


        $query->execute();

        $num = $query->rowCount();
        if ($num == 1) {
            echo  "Nome de usuário ".$usuarioProfessor." já existente!!!!";


        } else {

        $nomeProfessor=$_POST['tNomeProfessor'];
        $matriculaProfessor=$_POST['tMatriculaProfessor'];
        $emailProfessor=$_POST['tEmailProfessor'];
        $senhaProfessor=$_POST['tSenhaProfessor'];
        $redigitarProfessor=$_POST['tRedigitarProfessor'];

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO professor (nomeProfessor, usuarioProfessor, matriculaProfessor, emailProfessor, senhaProfessor, redigitarProfessor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->bindParam(1, $nomeProfessor);
        $sql->bindParam(2, $usuarioProfessor);
        $sql->bindParam(3, $matriculaProfessor);
        $sql->bindParam(4, $emailProfessor);
        $sql->bindParam(5, $senhaProfessor);
        $sql->bindParam(6, $redigitarProfessor);
        $sql->execute();

            if(!$sql){
                echo 'erro na consulta: '. $db->errno .' - '. $pdo->error;
            }else{
                echo "Insert realizado com sucesso";
            }

        $pdo = null;  
        }
    }

}
```